# Can JAX-WS return Boolean value?

Tags: vb.net, jax-ws, apache-axis

We developed JAX-WS using Apache Axis 2 which returns boolean value. While consuming this web service in vb.net it's throwing following error :

"**Argument not specified for parameter 'returnSpecified' of 'Public Sub MyMethod(Item as MyWebservice.Item, ByRef return As Boolean, ByRef returnSpecified as Boolean)'**"

My method in Jax-WS expects single object parameter, where as in the client code it's expecting three parameters as follows :

```
Dim Myws As New Webservice.MyWebservice
Dim MyItem As New Myws.Item
Myws.myMethod(MyItem, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Whereas, if we return String type then it works as follows and everything works fine:

```
Myws.myMethod(MyItem)
```

Please let me know, whether we can return boolean values using JAX-WS.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign `Nothing` to simple type.

```
Dim retValue1 as Boolean
Dim retValue2 as Boolean
Myws.myMethod(MyItem, retValue1, retValue2)
```